# IIS7 and Classic ASP and Applications and Paths

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I yesterday received a zip file containing an old asp site from 2005. Its came in a folder called `ivx`.

I've unzipped `ivx` to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` and then created an application in `IIS` called `ivxapp` and pointed it to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ivx`. Now when I type `http://localhost/ivxapp`, I am able to access the index page.

My problem is, whoever designed that site, designed it when IIS5 or IIS6 was around. He's used paths like `<a href=""/new_posts.asp"">more...</a>` which leads to `http://localhost/new_posts.asp` and not `http://localhost/imagevertex/new_posts.asp`

The whole site is some 21000 lines of code and contains many many references like this. Then comes the problem with `<!--#include virtual = "/common/adminverify.asp" -->`

Instead of having to manually edit the entire code, do you know a way to get things going?

This site worked perfectly well on a production server. Right now it's on my local machine on Windows 7 64 home premium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to give this site a root-URL of its own, and not run it in a subdirectory of your localhost.

This is more of a web-administration question, but what you need to do is either run it under "localhost" directly, or add a domain-name to your network to run this site under.
The easiest for you right now is probably the first option.

**If you aren't running a different site under localhost already:**

Go to the IIS manager and click the 'localhost' site. On the right side of the IIS interface you can change the basic settings. Point the physical path to the ivx directory. You can reach the site directly on `http://localhost`.

**If you are already running a site under localhost you need to keep:**

Now, if you -are- already running a site on your localhost, the second easiest option is to run the ivx site under localhost, but on a different port. To accomplish that, click on the current ivx site in IIS, change the path in the same way as descibed above, and after that click on "bindings" in IIS, and change the PORT for the ivx site to something other than 80, for example 81.

The ivx site will then run on `http://localhost:81`, your current localhost will still run on `http://localhost`.

**The hard way: adding a host to your network or PC:**

The last option is to add a new hostname for the site to your network. You can add an A-record in your DNS for the ip-address of your server or add a host name to your HOSTS file in Windows on your server ("server" in the sense of the machine that runs the site, which can also be your local machine)
You can add a made-up name to the ip-address of the server, and in IIS' bindings add that name under "host name". this way you can run two different sites on the same machine, the "host name" seeting in IIS will make sure that calls to that specific hostname will reach the correct site. Adding it to the DNS of your network, or the HOST file in Windows will make sure the name is resolved to the correct machine (your webserver).

This last option is a little tricky of you've never done something like this before, but the first option works just as well.

Good luck!

Erik